# Xamarin.Forms - Images are not updating on iOS due to a cache problem?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am displaying an image URL using `ffimageloading:CachedImage`.

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage
     CacheDuration="0"
     Aspect="AspectFill"
     VerticalOptions="{Binding HasImageRatioSwitch}"
     HorizontalOptions="{Binding HasImageRatioSwitch}"
     Source="{Binding AvatarSource}"/>
```

(AvatarSource is the URL).

The problem is that when I change the image URL, the updated image isn't displayed and the old one remains instead. Only when I delete the app and rerun it is when the new image displays properly.

This only happens on iOS... On Android I get my expected result without any issues, directly after updating the image.

Thanks in advance.